# How to display and remove elements from a tkinter window to show different screens in a questionnaire

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a questionnaire through tkinter.

- My main screen is working as intended
- pressing the enter button also works
- on pressing login nothing works

Here is what I have done so far:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import customtkinter as ctk

def login():
    username=StringVar()
    password=StringVar()
    Label(window0, text="Enter username and password").pack()
    Label(window0, text="USERNAME:").pack()
    Label(window0, text="PASSWORD:").pack()
    # this block seems to be the problem:
    lbl1.after(10,lbl1.destroy())
    btn.after(100,btn.destroy())
    btn_login.after(100,btn_login.destroy())
    btn_register.after(100,btn_register.destroy())
    # end of problem block

def open_acc0():
    lbl1=Label(window0,text='User Account', fg='blue', font=('Helvetica', (16))).place(x=120,y=10)
    btn_login=Button(window0, text="Login",fg='blue', command=login).place(x=200, y=50)
    btn_register=Button(window0, text="Register",fg='blue', command=register).place(x=200, y=75)
    lbl0.after(10,lbl0.destroy())
    btn.after(10,btn.destroy())
   
window0=Tk()
window0.title("GPAQ model")
window0.geometry("800x400")
lbl0=Label(window0, text="Bienvenue au Questionnaire Mondial" "\n" " Sur la Pratique d’Activités Physique (GPAQ)", fg='blue', font=('Helvetica',(20)))
lbl0.place(x=120,y=5)

btn=Button(window0, text="Enter", fg='blue', bg='yellow', font=('Time new roman',(14)),command=open_acc0)
btn.place(x=350, y=100)
btn.login=Button

window0.mainloop()
```

I do not know how to proceed with the login function.

Comment: If the `register` function isn't necessary to reproduce the problem, please remove it from the example. The example should be as short as possible while still reproducing the problem. Also, the code as posted has some indentation errors.

Comment: note: `lable1.after(10,lbl1.destroy())` _immediately_ calls `lbl1.destroy()`

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley register function deleted from example.

Comment: Note that `lbl1` and `btn_login` are local variables inside `open_acc0()` that cannot be accessed outside the function.  Also they are `None` because they are result of `.place(...)`.

Comment: the main idea is to work on the same screen and not creating new screens. @ acw1668 you are write, i created window0 as a function and yes, variables in open_acc which are working before are not working now. any ideas on how  to call variable which are inside functions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I always recommend to use an OOP approach for tkinter projects, otherwise the overview will be lost quickly! Furthermore, as already noted in the comments, you try to access variables outside their scope: e.g. you create a `Label` in one function and try to remove it in another. Again, the OOP approach helps immensely to create a common scope.

Try it like this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Entry, Button, StringVar


class Questionnaire(Tk):
    # use the init method to instantiate all elements of your gui.
    # then use your methods (like login) to display or destroy them
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # instantiate the Tk class of wich you inherit
        # set Window title and geometry
        self.title('GPAQ model')
        self.geometry("800x400")
        # GUI elements for start screen get initialized and placed right away
        self.lbl0 = Label(self, text="Bienvenue au Questionnaire Mondial\nSur la Pratique d’Activités Physique (GPAQ)",
                          fg='blue', font=('Helvetica', 20))
        self.lbl0.place(x=120, y=5)
        self.btn = Button(self, text="Enter", fg='blue', bg='yellow', font=('Time new roman', 14),
                          command=self.open_acc0)
        self.btn.place(x=350, y=100)
        # all other GUI elements (and class variables) only get instantiated
        self.lbl1 = Label(self, text='User Account', fg='blue', font=('Helvetica', 16))
        self.btn_login = Button(self, text="Login", fg='blue', command=self.login)
        self.login_text = Label(self, text="Enter username and password")
        # I put the login fields and labels in a Frame so i can pack it in one line and use grid inside
        self.login_frame = Frame(self)
        self.username_label = Label(self.login_frame, text="USERNAME:").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)
        self.userpw_label = Label(self.login_frame, text="PASSWORD:").grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        self.username_entry = Entry(self.login_frame, textvariable=self.username).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10)
        self.userpw_entry = Entry(self.login_frame, textvariable=self.password).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10)

    def open_acc0(self):
        # destroy start screen elements
        self.lbl0.destroy()
        self.btn.destroy()
        # show open_acc0 screen elements
        self.lbl1.place(x=120, y=10)
        self.btn_login.place(x=200, y=50)

    def login(self):
        # destroy open_acc0 screen elements
        self.lbl1.destroy()
        self.btn_login.destroy()
        # show login screen elements
        self.login_text.pack()
        self.login_frame.pack()


window0 = Questionnaire()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window0.mainloop()
```

This should give you an idea on how to do it.

Two more things though:

- this is only a sample and might not resemble exactly your desired layout. Rather, this example is intended to show the basic procedure of how to display and remove elements
- I highly recommend using more descriptive names for your variables if you have a big project in mind!